# PHP preg_match false matches single quote

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone tell me why the following code is only matching `'It'` instead of `'It’s a me, Mario!'`.
The character group at the end does not include a single `’`.

```
$re = '/(todays saying is )(?:["“”„]*)(?P<quote>[^"“”„]+)(?:["“”„]*)/m';
$str = 'todays saying is “It’s a me, Mario!”.';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: You need to enable `u` flag.